# ZFS deduplication does not work

Tags: linux, zfs

I have created pool tank1 and fs tank/home.

```
[root@zfs]# zfs list
NAME         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank1       3.22G   381G  32.0K  /tank1
tank1/home  3.22G  16.8G  1.95G  /tank1/home
```

I crated two 1G files inside tank1/home from `/dev/zero`.Deduplication is turned on, compression is turned off:

```
# zfs get all | egrep 'dedup|compression'
tank1             compression           off                    default
tank1             dedup                 on                     local
tank1/home        compression           off                    default
tank1/home        dedup                 on                     inherited from tank1

# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank1   596G  4.84G   591G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

# zdb -D tank1
All DDTs are empty
# zdb -S tank1
Simulated DDT histogram:

bucket              allocated                       referenced          
______   ______________________________   ______________________________
refcnt   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE   blocks   LSIZE   PSIZE   DSIZE
------   ------   -----   -----   -----   ------   -----   -----   -----
   16K        1    128K    128K    128K    25.8K   3.22G   3.22G   3.22G
 Total        1    128K    128K    128K    25.8K   3.22G   3.22G   3.22G

dedup = 26400.00, compress = 1.00, copies = 1.00, dedup * compress / copies = 26425.81
```

Why does `zdb` output and `zpool list` does not show any deduplication and simulation `zdb -S tank1` shows 26400? How to turn deduplication on? I alsto tried `zfs set dedup=verify tank1`, the problem persist. What does output of `zdb -DD tank1/home` menas?

```
# zdb -DD tank1/home
Dataset tank1/home [ZPL], ID 165, cr_txg 963, 1.95G, 8 objects
```

Comment: Deduplication only starts being used after it is turned on. Older files wont be modified.

Comment: It is turned on, see the output of `zfs get all | egrep 'dedup|compression'`

Comment: That is not what I was calling you attention. If the files have been deployed *before* it was turned on, they wont use dedup.

Comment: Thank you, I delete files and copy it and it works now. How can I check which data are deduped? May I perform dedup just on files added added before ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ZFS deduplication only will take effect on files deployed *after* you enable deduplication.

It won't affect older files *before* deduplication was enabled.

To see how much dedup is saving, use the command `zpool status -D poolname` and pay attention to the `Total allocated blocks` versus `Total referenced blocks`.

Comment: I deleted my old pool tank and create new one named nfspool. I turn on dedup and create 5 files from `/dev/zero` and the problem occours again. Even when I set up dedup to verify. It looks like problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @dorinand Try it with meaningful data. I suspect something about trying it with /dev/null, will have to check it out.